# How to Implement a Timed Trial Application

Tags: windows-phone-8

I would like to be able to allow a user to use a feature for a certain amount of time, and then after that prompt the user to purchase the application if they wish to continue using the feature. Kind of like a 'teaser'. Essentially on my FeaturePage I would like to place some sort of overlay or popup that will cover (or block) the UI so the user cannot interact with it (but still see it, maybe slightly dimmed) and place a short message and button in the middle asking if he or she wishes to upgrade to continue using the feature. How would it be possible to create such an implementation? Basically after a 15 day period anytime the user navigates to the FeaturePage, one the page is loaded the overlay or popup is shown with the upgrade request and button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Creating trial apps for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

> Do not rely on usage time limited trials to protect your app’s value.
>   Typically, it is best to protect the value of your full mode app by limiting trial access to key code paths. A user may uninstall and retry an app without restriction so a trial design that offers full mode behavior for a limited time provides only inconvenience as a barrier to reuse.

Comment: Yes thanks. I have in fact read this before, but I was going to go with a timed trial anyways. But after much thought and comments such as yours I have decided to go with another route, which is blocking functionality after a certain amount of uses.