# How to Determine How Long an Application has been Downloaded

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

For a trial application, I have a need to determine how long an application has been downloaded or running on a Windows Phone device. I would like to compare this value to the current date/time, and then display a popup if the application is still in trial mode and has been running on the user's device for more than a certain number of days. What would be the best way to check this? Would I store the application's first ran DateTime in IsolatedStorage and query that value everytime the app is loaded? Is there a better way? And how exactly would I do this? To note, I am currently storing whether the application has been loaded for the first time or not in order to display a Welcome page with a few quick directions/tips.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Implement a Timed Trial Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286584/how-to-implement-a-timed-trial-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you would like to measure the time the app has been running (i.e. in the foreground).

You'll want to record a timestamp each time the app is launched/activated, and another one when it is closed/deactivated. You can compute the elapsed time from these two timestamps, and store this value in `IsolatedStorage`. If a value already exists in `IsolatedStorage`, you'll add your new elapsed time to the existing value. Then you can check at startup for the value stored, and decide what to do if it's over your threshold.

Here's (untested) code that I'd use to record timestamps in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
DateTime startTimestamp;
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
const int MAX_TRIAL_USAGE = 5;

void Start()
{
    startTimestamp = DateTime.Now;

    if (settings.Contains("ElapsedTime"))
    {
        TimeSpan elapsed = (TimeSpan)settings["ElapsedTime"];

        if (elapsed > TimeSpan.FromDays(MAX_TRIAL_USAGE))
        {
            // Trial has expired, do something
        }
    }
}

void Stop()
{
    TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - startTimestamp;

    if (!settings.Contains("ElapsedTime"))
    {
        settings.Add("ElapsedTime", elapsed);
    }
    else
    {
        elapsed += (TimeSpan)settings["ElapsedTime"];
        settings["ElapsedTime"] = elapsed;
    }

    settings.Save();
}
```

Finally, hook up those methods to the application lifecycle events:

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    Start();
}

private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Start();
}

private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Stop();
}

private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Stop();
}
```